# Недопустимый параметр был передан функции

Tags: c++

написал небольшой кодик на лабораторной работе:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;

    cout << "Vvedite text:" << endl;
    getline(cin, text);
    int i = 0;
    char c = 'C';
    char plus = '+';

    do { i++; } while (text[i] != plus && text[i - 1] != plus && text[i - 2] != c);

    cout << "C++ vpervie vstrechaetsa na indekse '" << i << "' .";
}
```

По условию задания надо вывести индекс, когда в тексте впервые встречается сочитание символов "С++".

При запуске на cpp. sh - все работает как надо :

[image]

При запуске в Visual Studio вылазит эррор :

[image]

Буду очень благодарен, если расскажете в чем тут дело, и чем можно попытаться исправить.

Comment: string::size_type loc = text.find_first_of ( "C++");

Comment: Во входной строке нет "С++". Иначе должно нормально отработать.

Comment: Так у вас же за пределы строки вылезет при отсутствии паттерна

Comment: `!= && != && !=` означает искать пока какую-то одну букву найдёте. Правильно `not ( == && == && ==) ` или `!= or != or !=` ;; начинать надо с `int i = 2;` ;; и проверять конец строки вам уже намекнули.